# How to install cURL in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, curl

I have downloaded cURL for Windows and when i click .exe file its not running. I dont know how to install could any one give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a console application. You have to run it from command line. You should add the folder where the exe file is located to the `PATH` environment variable so you can run it from anywhere.

You can [check the tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You could install cygwin (www.cygwin.com), search for cURL during the setup phase and make sure to include it. There's a ton of other handy tools in cygwin as well, so I'd recommend cygwin to anyone having to use Windows on a regular basis.